# php date() one hour ahead of server time (DST problem)

Tags: php, date, time, dst

I'm trying to troubleshoot and solve this problem:
the server I'm working on (php 5.2.9 on Linux),  has the correct local time (America/Buenos_Aires):

```
user@server [/home/site/public_html]$ date
Mon Nov  1 17:11:14 ART 2010
```

`php.ini` is set with `date.timezone = "America/Buenos_Aires"`
I also tried to set the timezone directly in the script with

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT|E_NOTICE);

//date_default_timezone_set("America/Buenos_Aires"); 
//echo  date_default_timezone_get(), "<br>";
echo "ini: ", ini_get('date.timezone'), "<br>";

$now = date("H:i:s T I");
$nowdate = date("Y-m-d");
echo $nowdate." ".$now;
?>
```

but to no avail, the result is

```
ini: America/Buenos_Aires
2010-11-01 18:11:14 ARST 1
```

when  it should read `17:11` (It's consistently one hour ahead). All I've found here and on the web pointed to

- date_default_timezone_set (which I tried)
- setting date.timezone in php.ini (which it is set)
- confusing server time with client time (which I'm not).

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
As suggested, I checked and as you can see in the code, PHP thinks it should be applying DST, and Argentina decided to not apply it this year. Any option besides waiting for a patch?

**EDIT 2:**
I tried dumping the timezones transition as suggested. I got the following:

```
The timezone America/Buenos_Aires switches to standard time on 20 Mar 2011 @ 02:00.
The new GMT offset will be: -10800 (ART)
```

Comment: Also check for daylight savings time settings.

Comment: thanks, PHP is indeed using DST. I'll update the question.

Comment: *(tipp)* using `error_reporting(-1);` will show every possible error, even when new levels and constants are added in future PHP versions.

Comment: @Gordon: thanks, I know. I like being explicit about the error reporting levels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037364/php-timezones-gettransitions-trustworthy) a few days back that suggested that PHP hasn't yet got wind of the fact that Argentina [got rid of DST only this year](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=51&syear=2010). It seems like this decision hasn't made it into the code base yet. (But it was not confirmed, so it's not 100% clear whether this was it.)

Maybe try [dumping your time zones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-transitions-get.php) the same way to see whether that applies to your PHP version, too.

**Update:** This indeed seems to be the problem. The best solution I can think of is to use an offset in the time zone, e.g. [`Etc/GMT-3`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Somebody should file a bug with bugs.php.net, there doesn't seem to be one for this.

Comment: I seemed to remember the same thing happening a few years ago... That might be it. Thanks!

Comment: This is espacially visible in the original question, as the wrong time is in "ARST" but the correct time is in "ART".

Comment: @Adriano good question! One thing would be to file a bug with bugs.php.net so it gets cleaned up - there doesn't seem to be a bug report yet. As to what to do, does `date_default_timezone_set()` accept a pure offset? Maybe you can force a `-0300` (or whatever's correct right now, I'm confused :) on it for the time being.

Comment: @Adriano it doesn't accept offsets, but try `Etc/GMT-3` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Comment: @Pekka Oh, yes, I can also use a different timezone, but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Adriano this looks like broken info. Apart from recompiling PHP with the correct timezone info, I don't think there is a way to fix it right now.

Comment: `Etc/GMT-3` gives me 23:40:13 instead of 17:40. `Etc/GMT+3` did the trick, though.

Comment: @Adriano strange, `ART` is officially `UTC-3`. Try `GMT+3` maybe it counts the wrong way? Edit: Ah, okay!

Comment: I also filed the bug in bugs.php.net, thanks for the suggestion. I have to say, having filled everything here made for an easy bug report.

Comment: You can just update the timezone database with "pecl install timezonedb".

Comment: @Adriano `@`-ing you to make you aware of @Artefacto's comment - good to know!